# Why is pagebeforechange event on JQueryMobile called twice?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to wrap my head around this, but can't really understand why.

The docs say this event is called first with a URL on the `data.toPage` and after with an Object, but on the first page of the site, it is called twice with an object and no clear way to figure out this is a duplicate event.

Is there any other way to deal with that whitout a global var `alreadyDealtWithThis`?

Comment: `pagebeforecreate` or `pagebeforechange`?

Comment: pagebeforechange Updated question.

Comment: this is the normal behaviour, it fires on current page and the page you're about to navigate to.

Comment: Problem is that I can't distinguish between the two pagebeforechange fires because they are absolutely equal when navigating into the site for the first time.

Comment: if `data.options.fromPage` is `undefined`, it means that first page is shown http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/s5bjj/ you can even use `pagecontainerbeforetransition` which fires once. In jQM 1.5 it will replace second call of `pagebeforechange`.http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/ALpLG/

Comment: @Omar, I am still confused. On your first example, the event fires twice. How to distinguish between them without a global var? Besides that, if I am constructing the very first page based on JSON data gathered on an Ajax call, when should I do that? On the First or the second `pagebeforechange`call? And `pagecontainerbeforetransition` is fired _after_ the next page is already determined and on DOM, making it impossible to use it for creating the page. Am I wrong? THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR YOUR TIME.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55996/discussion-between-omar-and-motoboi).